# RVM is currently 1.9.2, want to run my app on 1.8.7, what should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm new to RVM.

So I have a RVM setup that has ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.

I want to know test the app in 1.8.7 with rails 3, what should I do?

Just change RMV's to 1.8.7 and navigate to the directory where my Rails app is?

Do I have to run bundle install again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, assuming you already installed 1.8.7 with RVM: `rvm install 1.8.7`, and loaded the rails 3 gem (remember, never use sudo with rvm).  Then it's just:

```
$> rvm 1.8.7
$> cd /path/to/myApp
$> bundle install
$> rails server
```

Update: as tinifni points out in the comments, you may want to create a new gemset for your 1.8.7 installation to keep your gems separate from those already installed:

```
$> rvm gemset create rails3dev
$> rvm 1.8.7@rails3dev
$> cd /path/to/myApp
$> bundle install
$> rails server
```

Of course, there's all this and more in the [the official RVM documentation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Comment: You may want to create a gemset to keep the gems required by your Gemfile separate from any gems installed on your 1.8.7 ruby.

Comment: RVM doesn't automatically sandbox gemsets by ruby version?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment before I saw your response. Each ruby has its own gem directory but you can create the gemset to have a separate gem directory within the current ruby.

Comment: EDITED: @tinifni, gotcha, we're on the same page and you're right. @Blankman, if you're already running 1.8.7, then you may want to create a new gemset -- learn more here: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

Comment: i use sudo, or I think I have at some point maybe it was just to install gems not sure, but why not?

Comment: RVM automagically operates as a user, not a root, and handles all the relevant permissions for you.  The way they put it is: `RVM helps ensure that all aspects of ruby are completely contained within user space, strongly encouraging non-root usage. Use of RVM rubies provide a higher level of system security and therefore reduce risk and overall system downtime. Additionally, since all processes run as the user, a compromised ruby process will not be able to compromise the entire system.`

Comment: That said, (and this is the confusing bit), if you switch back to your system ruby (`rvm system`) then you will again have to use sudo for gem installation.  This is because RVM doesn't take over existing ruby installations, so `rvm system` is essentially turning RVM off and returning you to pre-RVM times.  It's probably best to move all of your development over to RVM rubies so that you can avoid those workflow headaches.